# Evaluating lm where training data has been automatically transformaed with dummy variables

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm trying to use statisticalmodeling package to evaluate a model and also look at effect sizes:

```
library(caret)
library(statisticalModeling)

a_model <- train(
  Sepal.Length ~ Species + Sepal.Width,
  data = iris,
  method = "lm"
)

statisticalModeling::effect_size(a_model$finalModel, ~ Species, data = iris)
```

During fitting the model, r automatically converts categorical variable Species to a dummy variable - great, I don't have to worry about that.

However, this is throwing an error when I try to evaluate the model. The last line above gives:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Speciesversicolor' not found

Putting my question another way, is it possible to retrive the transformed data that r used to build the model? I culd then pass this into the data parameter of the statisticalmodeling functions.

I tried switching `data = iris` to `data = a_model$trainingData` but encountered the same message.

I don't encounter this issue using base r linear model, only with the caret derived one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid it using default S3 method of `train`.

```
b_model <- train(x = iris[, c("Species", "Sepal.Width")], 
                 y = iris$Sepal.Length, 
                 method = "lm")

identical(a_model$finalModel$coefficients, b_model$finalModel$coefficients)  # TRUE

statisticalModeling::effect_size(b_model$finalModel, ~ Species, data = iris)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. By S3 method, does that mean only including the exact variables from the training data frame? It looks like that's what you are doing

Comment: As far as I know, yes it does (see `help("train", "caret")`).

Comment: I tried this S3 method using dplyr select rather than ```df[, c("var1", "var2")]``` but it won;t run, which is odd because if I compare str of ```select(iris, c("Species", "Sepal.Width"))``` with the x = method you have above they appear exact same :-/

Comment: `tbl_df` probably doesn't supported. Maybe `select(as.data.frame(df), colnames)` works.